# Creating a subplot of pdp plots in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am using `pdpbox` to create a pdp plots for each of 50 features in a model. I have successfully created and saved these plots using:

```
# pdp_plot (https://pdpbox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pdp_plot.html)
for i, feat in enumerate(list_features):
    # increase i by 1 to help with name formatting
    n_feat = i + 1

    # pdp_isolate (https://pdpbox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pdp_isolate.html)
    pdp_dove = pdp.pdp_isolate(model=model,
                               dataset=df_train,
                               model_features=list_features,
                               feature=feat)

    # generate plot
    fig, axes = pdp.pdp_plot(pdp_isolate_out=pdp_dove,
                             feature_name=feat,
                             plot_pts_dist=True)

    # save figure
    if n_feat < 10:
        n_feat = '0{0}'.format(n_feat)
    # save figure
    plt.savefig('{0}_pdp_{1}.png'.format(n_feat, feat))
```

I could stop here if I want as I have all the plots in my working directory in a formatted and organized manner. However, I am wondering if it would be possible to add each plot to a subplot grid with `nrows=5` and `ncols=10`. Thank you in advance!